# Javascript variable in Jquery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, live, datatables

I am not sure if this question relates to Javascript or more to Jquery. And it seems really simple but I am stuck.

I am trying to assign a javascript variable to a jquery DataTables function.

```
[script]
//Not working

var counter = 0;
function testfunction(){
doSomething();
counter++;        
}

$(function() {

var newId = "#table" + counter;

$(newId).live('dblclick', function () {
    alert("test");
});

});

[/script]
```

$("#table") refers to a table id in my html. However, this does not work. The below version works instead.

```
[script]
//Working version

$(function() {

//var newId = "#table1"

$("#table1").live('dblclick', function () {
    alert("test");
});

});
[/script]
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You should post your complete code, as that looks completely fine...

Comment: Try either 'newId.live('dblclick', function () {' or 'var $newId="#table";'

Comment: @reporter: Why would that work?

Comment: @brettz9 I've got a theory that there is a difference between a "normal" javascript object and a "jquery" object. But I have also to say, not all jquery functions can be applied to a "normal" javascript object. According my experience only 60 till 70 percent of all functions can be applied.

Comment: @brettz9: You are right. The original code is fine. I have edited the code, in particularly the 3rd line.

Comment: but I saw a mistake of mine. I think it must be 'document.getElementById(newId).live('dblclick', function () {'. I'm very sorry.

Comment: Have you tried alert(newId) to see what the actualy string generated is? Might be doing something weird?

Comment: @reporter: I have tried that too, it doesnt work.

Comment: @Abe: Yup, I have tried that too. It displays nicely as a number.

Comment: This is random but try newId=table1 and do $('#'+newId).live...

Comment: @Abe: Tried that too.. it doesnt work..

Comment: ok instead of var newId = "#table" + counter; do "$newId = "#table" + counter;"

Comment: @Abe Did you mean use $newId.live? That doesnt work as it will give a javascript error

Comment: @Abe: nope.. cant get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Its quite difficult to say, but here is my attempt at fixing it, try below

```
[script]
var counter = 1;
var newId = "#table" + counter;
$(function() {    

$(newId).live('dblclick', function () {
    alert("test");
});

});

[/script]
```

If that works then it's because your using variables locally, and 'live' can no longer access the variable. have you tried an alternative function, like $(newId).click().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it did not solve my problem, it allowed me to debug a bit more. Take a look at my code above. I think the problem lies in counter. It does not register the "counter++" in testfunction().

Comment: I have confirmed, counter++ is not performing as it should

Comment: Yup, just added. Your code is great works perfectly fine if I dont call the testfunction()

Answer (score 0):

You never call **testfunction** to increment the counter variable. Therefore, **newId** will have the value *table0* instead of *table1*.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
function testfunction(){
    doSomething();
    counter++;        
}

$(function() {

    testfunction(); //Call testfunction to increment the counter.

    var newId = "#table" + counter;

    $(newId).live('dblclick', function () {
        alert("test");
    });

});
```

[Here is a working JsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/dMeAj/1/)